# Can people using different computers edit the same .blend file at once?

Tags: blend-files

I was wondering if it was possible to make a multiplayer blender file, almost like Google Docs. If there is, can anyone help? thanks, sorry for the strange question

Answer (score 8):

Currently this isn't possible and would require major changes to Blender.

Typically larger projects divide assets into many files so people can work on different parts simultaneously, this can be done so assets can be re-used in many places using Blender's [library linking system](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html).

Its also common to use a version control system, such as [Git](https://git-scm.com/videos), [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org), [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org)... ([or many others](http://www.slant.co/topics/370/~revision-control-systems)), to manage files for larger projects.

For reference, Mango Open Movie used [this structure](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Org:Institute/Open_projects/Mango/Production_Directory).

Comment: Guess this is the link for Mano Open Movie now... https://mango.blender.org/ .. can't see any blend files though - too bad, I would have loved to see how it's structured.